# Is this reading of the index set in the definition of independent sigma algebras correct?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Am I understanding the index set / loop index variables correctly in the following definition?

> Let $(Ω, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space (i.e., $Ω $ is a nonempty set, $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $Ω,$ and $\mathbb P$ is a nonnegative measure on the measurable space $(Ω, \mathcal F)$ having total mass $1$); and, for each $i$ from the (nonempty) index set $\mathcal I,$ let $\mathcal F_i$ be a sub $σ$-algebra of $\mathcal F.$ I will say that the $σ$-algebras $F_i,$ $i \in \mathcal I,$ are mutually $\mathbb P$-independent or, less precisely, $\mathbb P$-independent, if, for every finite subset $\{i_1, \dots , i_n\}$ of distinct elements of $\mathcal I$ and every choice of $A_{i_m} \in \mathcal F_{i_m}, 1 \leq m \leq n,$
>
> $$ \mathbb P (A_{i_1} \cap · · · \cap A_{i_n})= \mathbb P (A_{i_1}) · · · \mathbb P(A_{i_n})$$

My intuition is that if

$$\mathcal I =\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$$

there are $8$ sigma algebras $$\mathcal F_1,\dots,\mathcal F_8$$

and the finite subset $\{i_1, \dots , i_n\}$ with for example $n=3$ could be $\{i_1=3,i_2=7, i_3=8\}$ (i.e. not necessarily consecutive) pointing to the sigma algebras

$$\{\mathcal F_{i_1}=\mathcal F_3,\; \mathcal F_{i_2}=\mathcal F_7,\; \mathcal F_{i_3}=\mathcal F_8\}$$

from which a set respectively within each of these $n=3$ sigma algebras  will be chosen indexed by $m,$ ranging from $m=1$ to $m=n=3.$

so that $A_{i_1}\in \mathcal F_3, \; A_{i_2}\in \mathcal F_7$ and $A_{i_3}\in \mathcal F_8.$ And

$$\mathbb P(A_{i_3}, A_{i_7}, A_{i_8})=\mathbb P(A_{i_3}) \mathbb P(A_{i_7}) \mathbb P(A_{i_8})$$

with the understanding that we could have chosen any $n$ ranging from $n=1$ to $n=8$ to repeat the test.

Comment: More or less, but you have typos. At the end of the definition part, do you mean multiplication, not intersection on the right side? And before “with the understanding” do you mean $\mathbb P (A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}\cap A_{i_3})$ on the left? The definition basically says that $\mathcal F_i$ are independent if it is always true that the measure of the intersection of finitely many sets, one from each $\mathcal F_i$, is the product of the measures of the individual $\mathcal F_i$. Note that the index set need not be finite - infinitely many sub $\sigma$-algebras can be $\mathbb P$-independent.